# margin right doesn't work inside block

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to set the margins to a text, however margin-right doesn't seem to work inside message.
Why?

css:

```
  message
  {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 119, 212, 100);
  line-height: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  .messageotext
  {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0px;
  }
```

html:

```
  <message><span class="messageotext">prova</span></message>
```

I want the text to be out the screen so I can translate it by scripting language from right to left.

Comment: Why don't you use "display: none"?

Comment: display none doesn't render the text. Text shouldn't be shown in the beginning but, in each frame update, it should translate of x pixels. Basically I want a moving text from right to left.

Comment: Have you checked out the jQuery library?

Answer (score 1):

You have given `width:100%` and the parent is `fixed` so it will not effect 
If you remove your `width:100%` of `span` you will see `margin-right`

[image]

so you can add `text-align:right` to parent which will show the effect of `margin-right` or you can also use `float:right`

Demo - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/27cgwgej/)

Removed browser default styles by adding

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
message {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(26, 119, 212, 100);
  line-height: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}
.messageotext {
  /*  width: 100%;*/
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<message><span class="messageotext">prova</span>
</message>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your class messageotext with the following code:

```
.messageotext {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Then you can decrease the value of left property to translate it from right to left.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `float:right`

or you can also use only `right:0px` if `position` is `absolute`